# PHP instead of printing one array with a few elements, prints number of arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm playing around with PHP from a couple of months now, I'm trying to print the result of a select query in form of an array, but the issue is that my code's logic isn't correct, and I'm unable to find the problem. Most probably I'm using loops in an inappropriate manner.

I'm using arrays for the first time.

I've done a bit of research, but to no avail.

**PHP code:**

```
$data = array();
$selectquery1result = mysqli_query($sqlconnection , $selectquery1);
if (mysqli_num_rows($selectquery1result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectquery1result)) {
        $data[] = $row['U_id'];
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

I've defined `$sqlconnection` and `$selectquery1`.

My SQL Server has two records for `$selectquery1`.

**Actual results**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 10
)
```

I don't know why but the number of arrays is the same as the number of rows that should be returned for `$selectquery1`.

**Expected results**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 10
)
```

So, any help with that would be very helpful for me.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: its bound to happen, `print_r` executes every time the while loop is valid

Comment: put `print_r($data);` outside of while loop

Comment: so first iteration, the data is pushed inside `$data`, so it shows 1 item inside, second iteration, another push inside, then it shows two inside. that is the correct behaviour, if you want to see the contents once, put the `print_r` outside the loop after that block

Comment: Thanks, @Ghost this solved my problem,

Comment: You may also want to look at [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) in circumstances when you just loop and add the result into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing your array each iteration of a while loop. Instead you should put your `print_r` statement outside the loop body.

```
$data = array();
$selectquery1result = mysqli_query($sqlconnection , $selectquery1);
if (mysqli_num_rows($selectquery1result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectquery1result)) {
        $data[] = $row['U_id'];
    }
print_r($data);
}
```